# redux function mapDispatchToProps error in calling an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to get a list of repositories from GitHub's API using redux in reactjs, but I get this error:

> ./src/components/layouts/page/index.js Line 14:  Parsing error:
>   Unexpected token

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
         ^
    return {
         fetchRepos: function() {
         dispatch(fetchRepos());
```

These are my files:

**actions.js**

```
export function fetchRepos() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_REPOS_REQUEST'
    });

    return fetch('curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=sort=stars&order=desc')
      .then(response => response.json().then(body => ({ response, body })))
      .then(({ response, body }) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_REPOS_FAILURE',
            error: body.error
          });
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_REPOS_SUCCESS',
            repos: body.repos
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Page from './components/layouts/page/index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Page />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import repos from './reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    repos,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**reducers/reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  items: [],
  isFetching: false,
  error: undefined
};

function reposReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REPOS_REQUEST':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true
      });
    case 'FETCH_REPOS_SUCCESS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        repos: action.repos
      });
    case 'FETCH_REPOS_FAILURE':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        error: action.error
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  repos: reposReducer
});
```

**Page.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from '../list/index.js';    
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchRepos } from '../../../actions/actions';
import './page.scss';

class Page extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchRepos();
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      fetchRepos: function() {
        dispatch(fetchRepos());
      }
    };
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      repos: state.repos
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <List items={this.props.repos}/>
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Page);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps` need to be defined outside of your component in order to be used by `connect`:

```
class Page extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchRepos();
  }

  render() {
    const { repos } = this.props;

    return <List items={repos} />;
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchRepos: () => dispatch(fetchRepos())
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  repos: state.repos
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Page);
```

For more information refer to [this](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial).

Comment: Hey, the error is gone, but I get empty response object

Comment: On second look, you should probably get rid of the 'curl ' inside the `fetch()` call in your `fetchRepos` method.

Comment: I did and still no response, StackOverflow saying I can't ask a question anymore

Comment: Maybe it's just a cool-down and you have to wait a little or you've reached your question limit and need to contribute positive received answers to "unlock" the ability to ask more questions. Please also accept this answer, since it solved your initial question. [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)